# Combine multiple sources with same Materialized Values

Tags: scala, akka-stream

The `combine` operator in akka streams has the following signature:

```scala
  def combine[T, U](first: Source[T, _], second: Source[T, _], rest: Source[T, _]*)(
      strategy: Int => Graph[UniformFanInShape[T, U], NotUsed]): Source[U, NotUsed]
```

I have multiple sources, all with the same `Mat`. I need to combine them whist preserving `Mat`.

I therefore need a function with the following signature:

```scala
  def combine[T, U](first: Source[T, Mat], second: Source[T, Mat], rest: Source[T, Mat]*)(
      strategy: Int => Graph[UniformFanInShape[T, U], NotUsed]): Source[U, Seq[Mat]]
```

The existing `combineMat` only accepts two inputs. I need unlimited.

Akka's implementation of combine is:

```scala
  def combine[T, U](first: Source[T, _], second: Source[T, _], rest: Source[T, _]*)(
      strategy: Int => Graph[UniformFanInShape[T, U], NotUsed]): Source[U, NotUsed] =
    Source.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._
      val c = b.add(strategy(rest.size + 2))
      first ~> c.in(0)
      second ~> c.in(1)

      @tailrec def combineRest(idx: Int, i: Iterator[Source[T, _]]): SourceShape[U] =
        if (i.hasNext) {
          i.next() ~> c.in(idx)
          combineRest(idx + 1, i)
        } else SourceShape(c.out)

      combineRest(2, rest.iterator)
    })
```

It uses `SourceShape` which does not support `Mat`s, so I don't think will work here.

Meanwhile the implementation of `combineMat` uses `viaMat` which will not work for multiple streams.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works:

```scala
import akka.stream.scaladsl.GraphDSL.Implicits._
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{GraphDSL, Source}
import akka.stream.{Graph, SourceShape, UniformFanInShape}

import scala.collection.immutable

object Combine {
  def combine[T, U, Mat](sources: immutable.Seq[Source[T, Mat]])(strategy: Int => Graph[UniformFanInShape[T, U], Mat]): Source[U, immutable.Seq[Mat]] = {
    Source.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(sources) {
      implicit builder => {
        sourceShapes => {
          val target = builder.add(strategy(sources.size))

          for ((source, index) <- sourceShapes.zipWithIndex) {
            source ~> target.in(index)
          }

          SourceShape(target.out)
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```